# Css gradient background shadow

Tags: css, gradient

I need to make css gradient to look like this, I have tried many online makers but didn't manage to make it to look exactly like this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the help of [gradient-generator](https://www.cssmatic.com/gradient-generator#'%5C-moz%5C-linear%5C-gradient%5C%28left%5C%2C%5C%20rgba%5C%28248%5C%2C80%5C%2C50%5C%2C1%5C%29%5C%200%5C%25%5C%2C%5C%20rgba%5C%28241%5C%2C111%5C%2C92%5C%2C1%5C%29%5C%2050%5C%25%5C%2C%5C%20rgba%5C%28246%5C%2C41%5C%2C12%5C%2C1%5C%29%5C%2051%5C%25%5C%2C%5C%20rgba%5C%28240%5C%2C47%5C%2C23%5C%2C1%5C%29%5C%2071%5C%25%5C%2C%5C%20rgba%5C%28231%5C%2C56%5C%2C39%5C%2C1%5C%29%5C%20100%5C%25%5C%29%5C%3B')

```css
body{
        background: rgba(204,242,191,1);
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(204,242,191,1) 0%, rgba(74,179,32,1) 50%, rgba(172,214,101,1) 51%, rgba(211,255,140,1) 100%);
        background: -webkit-gradient(left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(204,242,191,1)), color-stop(50%, rgba(74,179,32,1)), color-stop(51%, rgba(172,214,101,1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(211,255,140,1)));
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(204,242,191,1) 0%, rgba(74,179,32,1) 50%, rgba(172,214,101,1) 51%, rgba(211,255,140,1) 100%);
        background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(204,242,191,1) 0%, rgba(74,179,32,1) 50%, rgba(172,214,101,1) 51%, rgba(211,255,140,1) 100%);
        background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(204,242,191,1) 0%, rgba(74,179,32,1) 50%, rgba(172,214,101,1) 51%, rgba(211,255,140,1) 100%);
        background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(204,242,191,1) 0%, rgba(74,179,32,1) 50%, rgba(172,214,101,1) 51%, rgba(211,255,140,1) 100%);
        filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ccf2bf', endColorstr='#d3ff8c', GradientType=0 );
                
        margin:0;
        height:100vh;
       
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I follow a simple and easy to use site to generate my gradients fast and easy. Good UI and easy to use.

[Gradient Generator](https://cssgradient.io/)

Good luck.